# How does GROUP BY work?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table `Tab1` with attributes - `a1`, `a2`, ... etc. None of the attributes are unique.

What will be the nature of the following query? Will it return a single row always?

```
SELECT a1, a2, sum(a3) FROM Tab1 GROUP BY a1, a2
```

Comment: It will return one row per unique combination (or group) of a1 and a2.  If there is only one unique combination, you only get one row.

Comment: And the sum will tell you how many rows ended up in each group =)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`GROUP BY` returns a single row for each unique combination of the `GROUP BY` fields.  So in your example, every distinct combination of `(a1, a2)` occurring in rows of `Tab1` results in a row in the query representing the group of rows with the given combination of group by field values .  Aggregate functions like `SUM()` are computed over the members of each group.

Answer (score 17):

`GROUP BY` returns one row for each unique combination of fields in the `GROUP BY` clause.  To ensure only one row, you would have to use an aggregate function - `COUNT`, `SUM`, `MAX` - without a `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 11):

`GROUP BY` groups all the identical records.

```
SELECT COUNT(ItemID), City
FROM Orders
GROUP BY City;

----------------------------------------
13  Sacrmento
23  Dallas
87  Los Angeles
5   Phoenix
```

If you don't group by `City` it will just display the total count of `ItemID`.

Answer (score 4):

Analogously, not technically, to keep in mind its logic, it can be thought each grouped field having some rows is put per different table, then the aggregate function carries on the tables individually.

---

[Ben Forta](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135182794) conspicuously states the following saying.

> The `GROUP BY` clause instructs the DBMS to group the data and then
>   perform [the aggregate (function)](https://web.archive.org/web/20190514030619/http://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/sql-aggregate-functions/) on each group rather than on the entire result
>   set.
>
> Aside from the aggregate calculation statements, every column in your `SELECT` statement must be present in the `GROUP BY` clause.
>
> The `GROUP BY` clause must *come after* any `WHERE` clause and *before* any `ORDER BY` clause.

My understanding reminiscent of his saying is the following.

> As is `DISTINCT` keyword, each field specified through `GROUP BY` is
>   thought as grouped and made unique at the end of the day. The
>   aggregate function is carried out over each group, as happened in
>   [SuL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44509855/4990642).

Comment: `Aside from the aggregate calculation statements, every column in your SELECT statement must be present in the GROUP BY clause.` Isn't the opposite closer to the truth? I thought every column in the `GROUP BY` statement should be aggregated in `SELECT`?

Comment: @Yuras **Exactly, no.** Fields in SELECT must be in GROUP BY, but not vice versa. Glance at the following links please, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11837318/4990642 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38707811/4990642