# Understanding GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

`SELECT a,b from <table_name> GROUP BY  a,b,c`.

Is the above a valid sql statement?

Comment: Not really since you are missing a table name!

Comment: Why are you asking this? Have you tried the above in MySQL and it's failed with a supposedly incomprehensible error, or are you just curious?

Comment: I am curious. as far as my understanding goes, only aggregate functions will be allowed on columns specified in the SELECT clause that do not appear in the GROUP BY clause. Also, i wanted to know, is it mandatory to include all the columns specified in the GROUP BY to be included in SELECT clause.

Answer (score 4):

Not without a table name it is not. If it had a table name it would be valid, but probably not very useful.

Typically one would use GROUP BY clauses in conjunction with some aggregate function (SUM, COUNT, MAX, MIN, etc.) to derive some values related to the grouped fields.

Comment: Sorry about that, SELECT a,b from <table_name> GROUP BY a,b,c. This was the statement.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that query is legal SQL. Whether it's **useful** SQL is another matter entirely.

The query

```
select a , b
from foo
group by a,b,c
```

Does the following:

- groups the rows from the source table into distinct groups, 1 for each unique combination of columns `a`, `b` and `c`.
- Each such group is then collapsed into a single row containing the grouping columns and the values of any required aggregate functions required by the query.
- The resulting result set is then returned to the caller, tossing any unwanted columns (in this case, column `c`).

Since one of the grouping columns is discarded, the specified query is not guaranteed to be a set of unique rows. It might well contain duplicates. For instance, if `group by` came up with these groups to be returned:

```
A  B  C
-  -  -
0  0  0
0  0  1
0  1  0
0  1  1
1  0  0
1  0  1
1  1  0
1  1  1
```

The results set returned by the query would be

```
A  B
-  -
0  0
0  0
0  1
0  1
1  0
1  0
1  1
1  1
```

And so, not necessarily useful.

Comment: It is the most helpful answer by a landslide. +1 after some years

Answer (score 2):

If you include a table name I guess you're asking if you can group by an unselected element c. Yes you can.

Comment: yes, thanks for the clarification. While formatting the question, i forgot to include the table_name.

Answer (score 1):

No - You need a table.

`SELECT a,b FROM myTable GROUP BY a,b,c`

where myTable is the table you are selecting from (which must have columns a,b and c).

Answer (score 0):

No- because you didn't specify a table name. If you had, then yes, it's certainly valid for mysql, not sure about Oracle (which validates GROUPing very differently). But it doesn't make any sense...

```
a  b  c
0  0  0
0  0  1
0  1  0
0  1  1
```

applying the query to the table above will give:

```
0 0 
0 0
0 1
0 1
```

And I don't see how that would be a meaningful result - if you don't want an aggregate value, then DISTINCT makes more sense - but gives a different result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, FROM `atable` 

0 0
0 1
```

Maybe if you explained the real reason youwere asking the question we could make a more sensible attempt at answering it.