# Why when using MIN function and selecting another column, we require GROUP BY clause? Doesn't MIN return single record?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables `vehicles` and `dealership_vehicles`. The `dealership_vehicles` table has a price column. The `vehicles` table has a column `dealership_vehicle_id` which relates to the `dealership_vehicles` id column in the `dealership_vehicles` table.

I wanted to return just the vehicle make of the cheapest car.

Why is it that the following query:

```
select 
    vehicles.make, 
    MIN(dealership_vehicles.price) 
from 
    vehicles inner join dealership_vehicles 
    on vehicles.dealership_vehicle_id=dealership_vehicles.id;
```

Returns the error:

```
column "vehicles.make" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Since MIN function returns a single value it is plausible that SQL query can be constructed that will return a single value without needing GROUP BY.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need GROUP BY with AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998552/why-do-we-need-group-by-with-aggregate-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to know the make of the cheapest car. The easiest way to do this is

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.MAKE
  FROM VEHICLE v
  INNER JOIN DEALERSHIP_VEHICLES dv
    ON v.DEALERSHIP_VEHICLE_ID = dv.ID
  WHERE dv.PRICE = (SELECT MIN(PRICE) FROM DEALERSHIP_VEHICLES);
```

Note that because multiple vehicles might have the "cheapest" price it's entirely possible you'll get multiple returns from the above query.

Best of luck.

## EDIT

Another way to do it is to take the minimum price, by make, then sort by the minimum price, and then just take the first row. Something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT v.MAKE, MIN(dv.PRICE)
          FROM VEHICLE v
          INNER JOIN DEALERSHIP_VEHICLES dv
            ON v.DEALERSHIP_VEHICLE_ID = dv.ID
          GROUP BY v.MAKE
          ORDER BY MIN(dv.PRICE) ASC)
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! A single query that will return JUST the make of the cheapest vehicle. I just couldnt put it into SQL context.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the term "GROUP BY" as "for each." It's saying "Give me the MIN of dealership_vehicles.price for each vehicles.make"

So you will need to change your query to:

```
select 
    vehicles.make, 
    MIN(dealership_vehicles.price) 
from 
    vehicles inner join dealership_vehicles 
    on vehicles.dealership_vehicle_id=dealership_vehicles.id
Group by vehicles.make;
```

Comment: This actually makes sense. I thought MIN() function returns a single record? Which I thought would go in dealership_vehicles table find the min price in that column and return the vehicle make that has that min price. The query above returns multiple records.

Comment: @O.MeeKoh: `MIN` returns a single *value*, but that value will be tacked on to each row, so you'll still get a bunch of rows. If you didn't group rows by the other fields, the results would almost never be what you'd want anyway. In your case, it would have been a bunch of rows like `(make, MIN(all the rows))` if it'd worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the make of the cheapest car, then no aggregation is needed:

```
select v.make, dv.price
from vehicles v inner join
     dealership_vehicles  dv
     on v.dealership_vehicle_id = dv.id
order by dv.price asc
fetch first one row only;
```

This gets a little more complicated if you want all rows in the case of ties:

```
select v.*
from (select v.make, dv.price, rank() over (order by price asc) as seqnum
      from vehicles v inner join
           dealership_vehicles  dv
           on v.dealership_vehicle_id = dv.id
     ) v
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So let's say after we join in the price we have the following table (i.e. stored in a #temp table):

```
#temp Vehicles table:
| Make   | Model |    Price |
|--------|-------|----------|
| Toyota | Yaris |  5000.00 |
| Toyota | Camry | 10000.00 |
| Ford   | Focus |  7500.00 |
```

If you query it for minimum price without specifying what you're grouping by, then only one minimum function is applied across all of the rows. Example:

```
select min(Price) from #temp
```

will return you a single value of 5000.00

If you want to know the make of the cheapest car, you need to filter your results by the cheapest price - it's a two step process. First you find out the cheapest price using min, then in a separate query, you find out which cars are at that price. Once you construct your query correctly, you will notice that this reveals what you might not have though of - you can actually have more than one cheapest make.

Example table:

```
#temp Vehicles table v2:
| Make   | Model  |    Price |
|--------|--------|----------|
| Toyota | Yaris  |  5000.00 |
| Toyota | Camry  | 10000.00 |
| Ford   | Focus  |  7500.00 |
| Ford   | Escort |  5000.00 |
```

query:

```
select * from #temp
where Price = (select min(Price) from #temp)
```

result:

```
| Make   | Model  |    Price |
|--------|--------|----------|
| Toyota | Yaris  |  5000.00 |
| Ford   | Escort |  5000.00 |
```