# How to disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to run a query on AWS Athena

```
SELECT t1.col1,
             t1.col2,
             t2.col2,
             t2.col3
    FROM "db"."table1" AS t1
    INNER JOIN "db2"."table2" AS t2
        ON t1.col2 = t2.col2
    GROUP BY  t1.col1, t2.col3
    HAVING COUNT(1) = 1 LIMIT 10;
```

but getting below error

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:10: '"t1"."col2"' must be an aggregate
>   expression or appear in GROUP BY clause

Is there any way I can disable **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** in AWS Athena or perform a GROUP BY on partial select columns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your expected result? When you `group by t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3` (and remove `t2.col2` from select clause, since it's equal to `t1.col2`), how does the result differ from what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about AWS Athena, but it seems like you may still run into issues even if you disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY (whatever that is).

You are getting a SYNTAX error - because you are not aggregating by `t1.col2` and `t2.col2`. In SQL, you *must* `group by` every column that is *not* part of an aggregate function. See this answer for why:
[Why do we need GROUP BY with AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998552/why-do-we-need-group-by-with-aggregate-functions)

Moreover, you may want to reexamine at your query - you are not `select`ing any aggregate function (`count, avg`, etc), and yet you are trying to `group` the results.