# Select Statements: Select referring previous select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two Queries which work independently; I need to combine these results.

1. Fetch all fields (including `wdate` and `Empid`), from `Fromdate` to `ToDate`.
2. Calculate a value (for efficiency, `Efc`), for a specific `wdate` and `Empid` from First Query.

1st Query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM  tblProductionEffcyDetails 
 WHERE wDate BETWEEN '06/26/2019' AND '07/25/2019' 
   AND worker = 'Techn' 
ORDER BY Empid, wDate
```

2nd Query

```
SELECT Cast(ROUND(SUM(Tstdmin) / NULLIF(SUM(TAvlblmin), 0) * 100,0) as int) AS [Efc] 
  FROM  tblProductionEffcyDetails 
 WHERE wDate='07/11/2019'  
   AND Empid='00021'  
GROUP BY wdate, Empid
```

That is, in this 2nd Query, the values for `wDate` and `Empid` should come from the results of the 1st Query.

Notes on the data/ table:

- Any particular date (`wDate`) or person (`Empid`) can have any number
  of entries.
- Efficiency (`Efc`) should be given just *once* per day
  (`wDate`) i.e. it should not have multiple values for a particular `wDate`.

Table structure is as below

```
SL      wDate       Avlbl_Mins  NP_Mins Empid   Name        Process         Model           Efc 
117571  7/13/2019   0           0       21      MARRY       Block removing      900-2930    80 
117572  7/13/2019   0           0       21      MARRY       Microscope checking 900-2929    Null 
116872  6/26/2019   430         75      52      SUGANTHI    Slab removing       900-2929    75 
116873  6/26/2019   0           0       52      SUGANTHI    Slab Removing       900-2528    Null
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I hope you don't mind that I edited your post for improving code formatting :)

Comment: Add sample data and expected result to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

you can get the particular `Empid` set for date between `06/26/2019` and `07/25/2019` using your 1st query and by connecting it to your second query you can sum it up.

```
SELECT Empid, Cast(ROUND(SUM(Tstdmin) / NULLIF(SUM(TAvlblmin), 0) * 100,0) as int) AS [Efc] 
  FROM  tblProductionEffcyDetails t
 WHERE t.Empid in ( 
     SELECT Empid 
      FROM  tblProductionEffcyDetails tb
     WHERE tb.wDate BETWEEN '06/26/2019' AND '07/25/2019' 
       AND tb.worker = 'Techn') and t.wDate BETWEEN '06/26/2019' AND '07/25/2019' 
GROUP BY t.wdate, t.Empid
```

I made the query as I understood your question, let me know if it didn't get the output you want. so I can change the answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about the first requirement from OP, "Fetch all fields"?

Comment: Hi thanks for the time, its not fetching all the fields. Actually my both individual queries working absolutely fine. but i need to combine those results without mismatch

Comment: if you need all the details you can change the query to SELECT t.*, Cast(ROUND(SUM(Tstdmin) / NULLIF(SUM(TAvlblmin), 0) * 100,0) as int) AS [Efc]  and try. If you are getting a aggregated function error meaning there are some field that cannot be grouped.

Comment: better if you can add the table structure in the question.

Comment: t.* also ask for aggregate functions. i have added the sample table in the comment.

Comment: by including the 'Group by' i get result i think. but is that correct to use like that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998552/why-do-we-need-group-by-with-aggregate-functions If you read this you'll get a better understanding why we get a aggregate function error when selecting all.

Comment: for example with this query `SL` number 117571 & 117572 will be grouped and will show you as one record. So when you "select *" what `model` should be displayed in that row. is it 900-2930 or 900-2929. These kinds of problems lead to aggregate function error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Empid, Cast(ROUND(SUM(Tstdmin) / NULLIF(SUM(TAvlblmin), 0) * 100,0) as 
int) AS [Efc] 
FROM ( 
 SELECT *
  FROM  tblProductionEffcyDetails tb1
 WHERE tb1.wDate BETWEEN '06/26/2019' AND '07/25/2019' 
   AND tb1.worker = 'Techn') as t  
GROUP BY t.wdate, t.Empid
```

Comment: What about the first requirement from OP, "Fetch all fields"?

Comment: Yes its not fetching all the fields, if i include * it asks for aggregate function.

Comment: The first Query fetches all values as in the table. second query calculates efficiency for the person on a particular date . So only a single value called efficiency needs to be added to the first query result appropriately.

Comment: I got it but what about other fields? how you want to get these other fields either aggregated or not.Please post some structured format to get better understanding of your problem.

Comment: SL wDate Avlbl_Mins NP_Mins Empid Name Process Model Efc                                                                                                                     
117571 7/13/2019 0 0 21 MARRY Block removing 900-2930 80
117572 7/13/2019 0 0 21 MARRY Microscope checking 900-2929 Null
116872 6/26/2019 430 75 52 SUGANTHI Slab removing 900-2929 75
116873 6/26/2019 0 0 52 SUGANTHI Slab Removing 900-2528 Null

Comment: i tried to paste small table. the first line upto Efc is header.

Comment: As a sample i gave 9 columns with 4 rows of values.