# Does Group by always need an aggregate function

Tags: sql

I don't have schema of my table unfortunately. The table has the following data.

[image]

I can run `order by` query but not `group by` query on this table

Works

```
select node_name, projection_name, row_count, used_bytes,ros_row_count, ros_used_bytes,ros_count 
from projection_storage 
order by projection_name;
```

Doesn't work and gives error `Column "projection_storage.node_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

```
select node_name, projection_name, row_count, used_bytes,ros_row_count, ros_used_bytes,ros_count 
from projection_storage 
group by projection_name;
```

Is it that `Group By` the selected columns need to be in an aggregate function `(COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG)` and also that they need to be of type number (no string, blobs etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Group by always need an aggregate function?

In an aggregation query, the unaggregated expressions in the `SELECT` need to be consistent with the expressions in the `GROUP BY`.  *All other expressions need to use aggregation functions*.

A `GROUP BY` query does not have to have any aggregation functions in the `SELECT`.

The most common type of consistency is that the unaggregated expressions are exactly the same.  However, the SQL Standard also supports:

- Expressions based on the expressions in the `GROUP BY` (and constants).
- `GROUP BY` keys that are missing from the `SELECT`.
- Any column from a table where the primary key or unique key is in the `GROUP BY`.

The third involves a concept called "functional dependence" and most databases do not (yet) support this functionality.

If you have a question about how to do something in particular, then ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, an explanation of what you want to do, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the `GROUP BY` clause, columns referenced must be all the columns in the `SELECT` clause that do not contain an `aggregate` function.

Refer [here](https://docs.actian.com/ingres/10s/index.html#page/SQLRef/GROUP_BY_Clause.htm) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is yes, you need always an aggregate function if you use a `Group By` statement.

As W3C says,

> The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

In my experience, I have never seen a `Group By` function without the aggregate function statement applied.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998552/why-do-we-need-group-by-with-aggregate-functions) a link on Stackoverflow about the `aggregate function`.