# Does it has to be that in SQL, aggregate function goes hand in hand with grouping?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Question in the title. Thanks for the time.

EXAMPLE  v

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  SUM(unit_price * quantity) AS total_price
FROM orders o
JOIN order_items oi
  ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need GROUP BY with AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998552/why-do-we-need-group-by-with-aggregate-functions)

Comment: "*Question in the title*" - that's not what the title is for. The full question should be part of the question. The title should be a short abstract

Comment: My mistake.  Won't happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, grouping does go hand in hand with aggregate functions, for any resulting column not contained within an aggregate function

Comment: GROUP BY is not required if you only have aggregate functions in the SELECT list, e.g. `select SUM(unit_price * quantity) from order_items`

Answer (score 0):

Grouping and the operations of aggregation are typically linked to three keywords:

- any [aggregation function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html)
- the [`GROUP BY`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-group-by/) clause
- the [`DISTINCT (ON)`](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/distinct.php) modifier after the `SELECT` keyword

You can use:

- aggregation functions alone when they are used on every field found inside the `SELECT` statement
- the `GROUP BY` clause alone - an allowed bad practice as you're intending to do an aggregation on your field but you're not specifying any aggregation function inside the `SELECT` statement (really you should go with `DISTINCT ON`)
- the `DISTINCT` modifier alone to select distinct rows (not fields)
- the `DISTINCT ON` modifier only when accompanied by an `ORDER BY` clause that defines the order for extracting the rows
- aggregation functions + the `GROUP BY` clause, that is forced to contain all fields found in the `SELECT` statement that are not object of aggregation
- the `DISTINCT` modifier + the `GROUP BY` clause - you can do it but the `GROUP BY` clause really is superfluous as it is already implied by the `DISTINCT` keyword itself.

You can't use:

- aggregation functions + the `GROUP BY` clause when non-aggregated fields included in the `SELECT` statement are not found within the `GROUP BY` clause
- aggregation functions alone when in the `SELECT` statement they are found together with non-aggregated fields.

When you can't aggregate because you need to select multiple fields, typically [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) + filtering operations (with a `WHERE` clause) can come in handy for computing values and row by row and removing unneeded records.