# How can I divide two HQL Count Results?

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, hql, grails-2.0

I want to compute the percentage of people who are not active divided by the percentage of people being active.

I will do something like the following HQL query but it did not work:

```
(select count(x) from People as x where x.active=false) / 
(select count(x) from People as x where x.active=true)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What doesn't work? If you're getting an NPE it could be from [this bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2917)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a group by clause to express this.  Here's how you could do it in Grails:

```
def countByAction = People.
    executeQuery("select active, count(*) from People group by active")*.
    toList().
    collectEntries{it}
println (countByAction[true])
println (countByAction[false])
```

Comment: Hi ataylor, I don't understand this... does it do what the user requested? can you add a description of how this works?

Comment: It uses a HQL group by clause to split the query results into groups.  In particular, it groups by the `active` column.  Since `active` is a boolean field, it will partition the results into two groups for true and false.  The `count(*)` selects the count of records in each group.  The results of the query would be something like `[[true, 10], [false, 20]]`.  This might be helpful to understand grouping in HQL/SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434657/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using HQL expression, I'm assuming you are using Hibernate. In this case I would recommend you using `@Formula` annotation. You may find additional information here:

- [Hibernate documentation - search for @Formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/)
- [Example of using @Formula annotation](http://gokhan.ozar.net/hibernate-derived-properties-formula-annotation/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
String hql = "select count(x)/(select count(x) from People as x where x.active=true) 
                 from People as x where x.active=false";

Long result = (Long) em.createQuery(hql).getSingleResult();
```

NOTE: above is untested

Answer (score 0):

I use **countBy*** Dynamic method that uses the properties of the domain class to query for the count of the number of matching records. see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/countBy.html