# HAVING SUM() Issue

Tags: sql

I want to add the total sales by date using the HAVING SUM () variable but it is not working as expected.

```
    SELECT
       sum(SalesA+SalesB) as Sales,
       sum(tax) as tax,
       count(distinct SalesID) as NumOfSales,
       Date
    FROM
       SalesTable
    WHERE
       Date >= '2014-03-01'
    GROUP BY
       Date, SalesA
    HAVING
       sum(SalesA+SalesB) >= 7000
    ORDER BY
       Date
```

The results are;

```
   |Sales| tax | NumOfSales | Date |
    10224| 345 |     1      |2014-03-06| 
     9224| 245 |     1      |2014-03-06|
     7224| 145 |     1      |2014-03-06|
```

If I remove the SalesA in the GROUP BY clause it seems to ignore my HAVING sum clause and adds all the totals.

I would like the results to sum all by date like this .

```
    |Sales| tax | NumOfSales | Date |
     26672| 735 |     3      |2014-03-06
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Remove SalesA from your group by.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434657/how-does-group-by-work    The problem is with group by..read this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to remove individual rows whose salesa + sales b < 7000 so that you only sum rows whose total SalesA + SalesB >= 7000?

```
SELECT
   sum(SalesA+SalesB) as Sales,
   sum(tax) as tax,
   count(distinct SalesID) as NumOfSales,
   Date
FROM
   SalesTable
WHERE
   Date >= '2014-03-01'
   and
   SalesA+SalesB >= 7000
GROUP BY
   Date
ORDER BY
   Date
```

Comment: Seems too Easy :) It fixed the problem i was having.

Comment: Thanks you all for the help

Comment: @automatic is it correct to use where with count(aggregate function) ??if yes please explain

Comment: shouldn't we use having ?

Comment: Aggregates and Having are fine, but in this case the data needed to be removed from the aggregate be for the aggregate was performed rather than removing a particular set out of the aggregate results

Answer (score 2):

You can try rewriting your SQL statement as follows.

```
SELECT
   sum(SalesA+SalesB) as Sales,
   sum(tax) as tax,
   count(distinct SalesID) as NumOfSales,
   Date
FROM
   SalesTable
WHERE
   Date >= '2014-03-01' AND SalesA+SalesB >= 10000
GROUP BY
   Date
ORDER BY
   Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `HAVING Sales >= 7000`

Comment: It is :), typo when i had entered it here

Comment: Edit your question then to reflect your real query

Comment: Also, if you want to group by `Date`, why don't you `GROUP BY Date`, why do you need SalesA column in group (or is that also a part of what you need). You should show an example of your input table.

Comment: if I remove the GROUP BY "SalesA" it adds all of the data returning all records Above 7k and below.

Comment: Well if you want to sum only those >= 7000 then you do it in WHERE, and not in HAVING. HAVING is applied only after the aggregate function. Try with `WHERE Date>=.... AND SalesA+SalesB >= 7000`