# How to use group by in SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server

I have problem with group by in SQL Server

I have this simple SQL statement:

```
select * 
from Factors 
group by moshtari_ID
```

and I get this error :

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'Factors.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is my result without group by :

[image]

and this is error with group by command :

[image]

Where is my problem ?

Comment: You need to learn about grouping. Please take a tutorial first

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What output are you trying to get?

Comment: The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns. In case,you are trying to achieve any aggregation,then only  go with this

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In general, once you start GROUPing, every column listed in your SELECT must be either a column in your GROUP or some aggregate thereof.  Let's say you have a table like this:

```
| ID | Name        | City        |
|  1 | Foo bar     | San Jose    |
|  2 | Bar foo     | San Jose    |
|  3 | Baz Foo     | Santa Clara |
```

If you wanted to get a list of all the cities in your database, and tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY City
```

...that would fail, because you're asking for columns (ID and Name) that aren't in the GROUP BY clause.  You could instead:

```
SELECT City, count(City) as Cnt FROM table GROUP BY City
```

...and that would get you:

```
| City        | Cnt |
| San Jose    |  2  |
| Santa Clara |  1  |
```

...but would NOT get you ID or Name.  You can do more complicated things with e.g. subselects or self-joins, but basically what you're trying to do isn't possible as-stated.  Break down your problem further (what do you want the data to look like?), and go from there.

Good luck!

Comment: *>...that would fail* Hmm, it [doesn't seem to fail](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79031b/1).

Answer (score 2):

When you group then you can select only the columns you group by. Other columns need to be aggrgated. This can be done with functions like `min()`, `avg()`, `count()`, ...

Why is this? Because with `group by` you make multiple records unique. But what about the column not being unique? The DB needs a rule for those on how to display then - aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply aggregate function such as max(), avg() , count() in group by.

For example this query will sum totalAmount for all moshtari_ID

```
select moshtari_ID,sum (totalAmount) from Factors group by moshtari_ID;
```

output will be

```
moshtari_ID    SUM
2              120000 
1              200000
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it,

```
select * 
from Factorys
Group by ID, date, time, factorNo, trackingNo, totalAmount, createAt, updateAt, bark_ID, moshtari_ID
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are applying group clause then you can only use group columns and aggregate function in select

syntax:

```
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n, 
       aggregate_function (aggregate_expression)
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions]
GROUP BY expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
[ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC ]];
```

Comment: This doesn't provide any additional element.