# How to count number of times each state appears in SQL table

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a SQL table with three columns: *name*, *date of birth*, and *current state*. I want to return a result-set with the number of times each state appeared in the original table. The result-set will have 2 columns: *state* and *count*.

I'm guessing I will need to use `GROUP BY` or `COUNT` but I haven't been able to put it together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use count and group by at the same select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722408/how-to-use-count-and-group-by-at-the-same-select-statement)

Comment: A nice brief explanation is [How does GROUP BY work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434657/how-does-group-by-work)

Answer (score 2):

The following syntax will work for *most* SQL engines:

> ```
> SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n,
>   COUNT(aggregate_expression)
> FROM tables
> [WHERE conditions]
> GROUP BY expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
> [ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC ]];
> ```
>
> #### Parameters or Arguments
>
> <sub>***expression1, expression2, ... expression＿n***
>  Expressions
> that are not encapsulated within the COUNT function and must be
> included in the GROUP BY clause at the end of the SQL statement.
>
> ***aggregate＿expression***
>  This is the column or expression whose non-null values will be counted.
>
> ***tables***
>  The tables that you wish to retrieve records from. There must be at least one table listed in the FROM clause.
>
> ***WHERE conditions***
>  Optional. These are conditions that must be met for the records to be selected.
>
> ***ORDER BY expression***
>  Optional. The expression used to sort the records in the result set. If more than one expression is
> provided, the values should be comma separated.
>
> ***ASC***
>  Optional. ASC sorts the result set in ascending order by expression. This is the default behavior, if no modifier is
> provider.
>
> ***DESC***
>  Optional. DESC sorts the result set in descending order by expression.</sub>
>  
> <sup>[1](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php)</sup>

Refer to documentation for the specific engine used:

- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)
- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-aggregate.html)
- [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#count)
- [T-SQL/SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

...etc

For the "*question*"

> <sub>I have a SQL table with three columns: name, date of birth, and current state. I want to return a result-set with the number of times each state appeared in the original table. The result-set will have 2 columns: state and count.</sub>

such a query could be constructed like this:

```
SELECT current_state as state, count(*) as count
FROM data 
GROUP BY current_state
```

See an example of this in [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/286c9/4).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php</sub>

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax!

Comment: @jarlh good idea - instead of citing the MySQL documentation (who knows why that documentation would have an example with out any _ON_ conditions for the JOIN?? :/ ...), it now includes a citation from a non-database Engine specific source and includes links to some of the most prominantly used r-DBMS engines

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this...

```
SELECT current_state, count(current_state) FROM table GROUP BY current_state
```