# T-SQL order by and take only the highest value

Tags: t-sql

I have a table where i want to retrieve the highest values of a category
ea:

```
UserA catA   4
userA catA 200
userA catB 100
UserA catA  50
userB catA 150
userB catC  10
userB catC 300
```

it should return

```
userA catA 200
userA catB 100
userB catA 150
userB catC 300
```

Order by and then take only the highest value.
And i wonder what's the best way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does GROUP BY work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434657/how-does-group-by-work)

Comment: group by can be used in many ways and sure stack overflow has grown so vast that somewhere some place in some answers something alike it is available however its a short question and there is a short answer here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select column1, column2, max(column3) as MaxColumn3 from TableName group by column1, column2
```

as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option can be using MAX() function with Partition By clause as follows

```
Select 
    distinct [user], category, max([value]) over (partition by [user], [category]) as MaxValue 
from UserCategoryValues
```

Many aggregation functions can be used with [Partition By clause in SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/count-and-row-number-function-for-n-of-m-rows-query.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select   [User], Category,max(Value) from UserCategory group by [User], Category order by [User]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it