# Using Aggregate String Functions in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, aggregate

I am currently having an issue where I have an enum named 'Privilege' where 0 = normal and 1 = privileged. These are assigned to jobs e.g. worker has normal privilege but CEO has admin privileges. An issue I have run into is where a user might have two jobs, where one is normal privileged and the other is admin privileged. I have written a query, in order to start sessions depending on the privilege,however when I use group by StaffID, I'm unsure on how to group by the highest privilege (1 being the case).

E.g.

```
else if ($pwdCheck == True){
    session_start();
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT staff.StaffID, role.Privilege FROM jobs
         INNER JOIN staff ON staff.StaffID = jobs.StaffID
         INNER JOIN role ON role.RoleID = jobs.RoleID GROUP BY StaffID
    ');

    $gettier = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    if($gettier["Privilege"] === 'normal'){
        $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['LoginID'];
        header("Location: staffindex.php?login=USERsuccess");
    }
    elseif($gettier["Privilege"] === 'privileged'){
        $_SESSION['AdminID'] = $row['LoginID'];
        header("Location: staffindex.php?login=ADMINsuccess");
    }
    exit();
}
```

This is where in all cases, wen I enter a privileged person, I am still redirected with the USERsuccess header. I assume I will need to use an aggregate string function (after some research) but I don't really understand how to apply it.

Please view the image to see query in action:
With Group By: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIZ8L.jpg
Without Group By: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOJxx.jpg

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you must write `sum(role.Privilege)` in select

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does GROUP BY work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434657/how-does-group-by-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't sort `enum` values numerically, but instead by their string representation, otherwise you could just use `MAX` directly on the values. But you can sort by `CAST`ing the values as integers e.g.

```
SELECT staff.StaffID, MAX(CAST(role.Privilege AS UNSIGNED)) AS Privilege FROM jobs
INNER JOIN staff ON staff.StaffID = jobs.StaffID
INNER JOIN role ON role.RoleID = jobs.RoleID GROUP BY StaffID
```

Assuming your `ENUM` has values `('normal', 'privileged')`, this will return a value of `1` for a user with only `normal` privilege and `2` for a user with either only `privileged` privilege or both `normal` and `privileged`. You can then change the check in your PHP to:

```
if($gettier["Privilege"] == 1){
    $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['LoginID'];
    header("Location: staffindex.php?login=USERsuccess");
}
elseif($gettier["Privilege"] == 2){
    $_SESSION['AdminID'] = $row['LoginID'];
    header("Location: staffindex.php?login=ADMINsuccess");
}
```

Note you can't use `===` in the comparison with `$gettier["Privilege"]` because the values returned from the query will be strings, not integers.

Comment: This is super, but this returns an error where Privilege is an undefined index?

Comment: @GoGoAllen sorry, forgot to give the value an alias. see my edit

Comment: Hmm, this still doesn't seem to work - doing this creates a blank page with no redirect. I added ((int)$gettier["Privilege"]) to both statements, however it still redirects to USERsuccess.

Comment: @GoGoAllen the db code works fine - see this demo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=39ecc51e702091e2a91b2ebbd4319f57. PHP is returning values as strings which is why the `===` fails, but casting to int should fix that. what do you get if you `echo $gettier["Privilege"];`?

Comment: The query seems to be all goods - I ran the if statements through with a   error_log(print_r($gettier,true)); at the end and it returned: "Array\n(\n    [StaffID] => 1\n    [Privilege] => 1\n)\n, referer: {localhost location}"

Comment: Is that the expected privilege level for that staff member?

Comment: Not sure, that was all that was returned in error.log

Comment: You will need a `WHERE` clause on your query to only select the privilege for a specific staff member

Comment: 'SELECT staff.StaffID, MAX(CAST(role.Privilege AS UNSIGNED)) AS Privilege FROM jobs
INNER JOIN staff ON staff.StaffID = jobs.StaffID
INNER JOIN role ON role.RoleID = jobs.RoleID WHERE staff.StaffID = 4 GROUP BY StaffID' - Upon entering this and entering the login details of this admin user, the login process still leaves a blank page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193752/discussion-between-nick-and-gogoallen).

Comment: Have you still got the log on $gettier? What does that say?

Comment: @GoGoAllen did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Hey, the query was good! I realised that since the page I was redirecting too had an if statement saying that if the user did NOT have USERID it would deny access to the page. Upon changing this, everything worked as expected. Thanks so much for your help nick :)

Comment: @GoGoAllen that's great news! That sort of thing can be so hard to debug...