# How to output only 1 if data same

Tags: sql

I try it, but didn't output like i want.

Example:

I have table like this :

```
+----+------+------+
| Id | Name | Total|
+----+------+------+
|  1 | Joni |   2  |
|  2 | Brad |   1  |
|  3 | Joni |   3  |
|  4 | Chuck|   1  |
|  5 | Brad |   3  |
|  6 | Brad |   5  |
+----+------+------+
```

And i want output like this :

```
+------+------+
| Name | Total|
+------+------+
| Joni |   5  |
| Brad |   9  |
| Chuck|   1  |
+------+------+
* Count total by Distinct name
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does GROUP BY work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434657/how-does-group-by-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can make your query like this for getting same result that you want -**

```
SELECT SUM(Total) as total,Name from table_name group by Name;
```

Comment: I try GROUP BY `Name`. And it works thanks

Comment: If it's worked for you, than upvote the answer brother.